# How to read a .txt file in a structured way?

Tags: c#

Summary of my goal:

I am creating a simple game to improve my knowledge of C#. It is a guessing game in which the program will write a sentence to the console with a word missing. The user has to type in the missing word correctly then the next sentence will load. I have stored these sentences in a .txt file structured so they can load in groups randomly. The file is structured so the missing word and the sentence it is contained in a line within a group split by a '[]'.

I just want to know what I should use to tell the program to load the lines within a group split with '[]' so it can keep organised within an array. Im assuming this is going to be using the File IO class but please could someone tell me if im wrong, give me an example or just tell me what I should be looking into. I have been looking into and experimenting File IO classes extensivley but I can't seem to find any examples online or in my books that show what I need.

Example of .txt:

```
cat - the cat purred
dog - the dog barked
[]
cake - I baked a cake
ate - the cake I ate was delicous
[]
```

**Any advice is appreciated.**

Comment: _File IO_ Good start. As opposed to yelling at us..

Comment: _I just want to know what I should use to tell the program to load the lines within a group split with '[]'_ - I'm not sure what your question is. You can read the file with `var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFilePath)` then use `string.Split` to get each part, and then replace the missing word in the second part -  so _the cat purred_ becomes _the ? purred_ with the 'answer' being 'cat' - but I don't understand what you want `[]` to mean?

Comment: I guess the [] are the placeholders for words to insert. - General advice: Break down the problem into smaller and smaller parts..

Comment: The answer here is JSON. Or XML. Or YAML. Or some sort of structured data interchange format for which there are commodity, off-the-shelf serializers and deserializers readily available across a wide variety of toolchains and languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to impose an easily parseable structure for data in a human readable and editable text file, then the first piece of advice would be to look at leveraging a format designed for it rather than rolling your own with vanilla text.

JSON, or Javascript Object Notation, would provide you a very easy to use way to create well defined attributes that can be grouped into clusters like what you've described. Better yet, C# and the .NET Frameworks have a number of very mature libraries for reading JSON into strongly typed classes from a file or other source, such as [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

A JSON representation of your data may look like:

```
[
   {
      'word' : 'cake',
      'beginningFragment' : 'I baked a ',
      'endingFragment' : '.'
    },
    {
      'word" : 'ate',
      'beginningFragment' : 'The cake I ',
      'endingFragment' : ' was delicious.'
    }
]
```

And a corresponding list and class might be set up in C#:

```
public class Sentence 
{
   public string Word { get; set; }
   public string BeginningFragment { get; set; }
   public string EndingFragment { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of performing a bunch of arbitrary operations on a text file, your structure is all there and ready to go.

Comment: Seems to work fine with Newtonsoft 12.0.3 by default on NET 4.7.2 and NET Core 3.1?

Comment: Downvoted because of using obsoleted `Newtonsoft.Json`. Use `System.Text.Json` instead for it is modernly designed, faster, and officially supported.

Comment: And .NET is no longer short of .NET Framework but .NET 5 that is a new version of .NET Core. Just use .NET Framework to explicitly specify the obsoleted framework.

Comment: Calling Newtonsoft obsoleted is a bit of a stretch, and you’ll note the question does not specify a .NET version, so sensible to give an example of one of the widely used and well supported libraries.

Comment: @Alsein there is **no way** that Newtonsoft.Json is obsolete - [the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) was updated to version 3.1.4 eight days ago, and contains preview versions for .net core 5.

Comment: @AdamG you're quite right, the case makes no difference, my apologies. I wonder if this is new, and I can now get rid of all the `JsonProperty` attributes in my code?!?

Comment: No worries, I did a double take and went to recheck myself when you pointed it out. The attributes probably don’t hurt for explicitness sake!

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` is for not breaking the legacy projects and not included in the framrwork(`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`). The existence of this package does not stand for that it is not obsoleted.

Comment: The question does not specify a .NET version but @AdamG used `NET` for `.NET Framework` which is no longer correct since `.NET` is now referring to .NET 5 (and future versions) as the unique platform of the whole .NET ecosystem base on the new version of .NET Core.

Comment: Your dedication to semantics is commendable, but I think the horse is dead ;) . Good for a re-read: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27761